# What event is triggered when the mouse pointer enters a MenuflyoutSubItem element?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

PointerEntered is triggered when the mouse pointer enters a MenuFlyoutItem, but not when it enters a MenuFlyoutSubItem. What event is triggered when the mouse pointer enters a MenuflyoutSubItem element? I want to capture the text property of the MenuflyoutSubItem element in an event handler when the mouse pointer enters it. (The reason I can't rely on the tapped event is because even just hovering over the MenuFlyoutSubItem opens its contained menu items.)  Here is the code:

```
public DynamicMenuTestPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            MenuFlyoutSubItem myItem = new MenuFlyoutSubItem();
            myItem.Text = "Item" + i;
            myItem.PointerEntered += MyItem_PointerEntered;        
            MyMenu.Items.Add(myItem);
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                MenuFlyoutItem mySubItem = new MenuFlyoutItem();
                mySubItem.Text = "SubItem" + j;
                mySubItem.PointerEntered += mySubItem_PointerEntered;
                myItem.Items.Add(mySubItem);
            }
        }
    }

    private void MyItem_PointerEntered(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // This does not work.  It is not triggered when the mouse pointer enters the menu flyout subitem.
        MenuFlyoutSubItem test = sender as MenuFlyoutSubItem;
        var menuFlyoutSubItemText = test.Text;

    }

    private void mySubItem_PointerEntered(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {   //This works. It is triggered when the mouse pointer enters the menu flyout item.
        MenuFlyoutItem test = sender as MenuFlyoutItem;
        var menuFlyoutItemText = test.Text;

    }
```

Here is a screenshot of the menu. When I hover over Item0, circled in red, the submenu opens. What event will enable me to capture the text, "Item0"?

[image: Menu Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the [MenuFlyoutSubItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.menuflyoutsubitem) doesn't fire the `PointerEntered` [RoutedEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.routedevent), you can wire an event handler for this [RoutedEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.routedevent).

```
myItem.AddHandler(PointerEnteredEvent, new PointerEventHandler(PointEnterHandler), true);
```

So your code will be like this:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        MenuFlyoutSubItem myItem = new MenuFlyoutSubItem();
        myItem.Text = "Item" + i;
        myItem.AddHandler(PointerEnteredEvent, new PointerEventHandler(PointEnterHandler), true);
        MyMenu.Items.Add(myItem);
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            MenuFlyoutItem mySubItem = new MenuFlyoutItem();
            mySubItem.Text = "SubItem" + j;
            mySubItem.PointerEntered += mySubItem_PointerEntered;
            myItem.Items.Add(mySubItem);
        }
    }
}

private void PointEnterHandler(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MenuFlyoutSubItem test = sender as MenuFlyoutSubItem;
    var menuFlyoutSubItemText = test.Text;
}

private void mySubItem_PointerEntered(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{   //This works. It is triggered when the mouse pointer enters the menu flyout item.
    MenuFlyoutItem test = sender as MenuFlyoutItem;
    var menuFlyoutItemText = test.Text;
}
```